connecting 5 solenoids to raspberry pi (can anyone do it or should i leave it to a pro?)
I'm opening a perfume spraying vending machine and I need to link 5 solenoids to raspberry bi. Is it easy or should i hire someone to do it? I live in vietnam and the language barrier is a setback for me.
Extra information: i need to connect raspberry pi to 5 solenoids that are connected to 5 different bottles of fragrances for a vending machine. when a customer for example, chooses the Sauvage perfume, that connected solenoid will open and spray a small amount of perfume etc. equipment being used: Parker 2-Way Solenoid Valve (Series 40), Kamoer KVP-12A Diaphragm Pump, 1N4007 Diode, SainSmart 4-Channel Relay Module,

It's easy enough that you can probably do it yourself if you're willing to invest a little time. Hint: Do not use MOSFETs; use bipolar. However: I’m voting to close this question because it lacks enough detail to be considered as a "legitimate" question here.

@Seamus - Just out of interest, why is a BJT preferable? Due to cost? MOSFET or bipolar to drive a solenoid valve?

@Greenonline: Many (not all) MOSFETs have a Vgs threshold that is too high to drive effectively from a 3.3V GPIO. Bipolar OTOH is driven by current, and only requires enough voltage to exceed the fwd diode drop in the B-E junction (Vbe=0.7V).

You could use ULN2803 or ULN2003 or as an alternative is using relays - see Connecting Pi to 16 solenoids - how?

@Greenonline: Both ULN parts are bipolar (Darlington BJT).

I prefer MOSFETs and yes they are now available with a low enough Vgs to work with a 3V3 port. However I am missing the information on the solenoids to size the drivers. What voltage, current, etc is needed, 100% duty cycle is assumed unless otherwise stated.

Please [edit] and add any additional info to the question, and not in the comments - that is not what they are for.

If you're not a pro, I would try a USB relay card. They're quite cheap and work well with the Pi. Also, you don't have the risk that you burn your Pi.

FWIW, regarding the bipolar solution, this question has a schematic showing how to use ULN2003A connections - it is really rather straightforward. Again, as Gil has already stated, the current needed to drive the solenoids needs to be known (and taken into account)
